# c# and LINQ where property-name of collection member is passed via function

Tags: c#, linq, generics, parameters

As always, help/comments thoughts are always appreciated, and appologies for the naivety of my programming.

I am trying to create a broadly applicable function which can be used in future research which involves block randomization. Each member of patientDataCollection will have a boolean property named something like interventionArm, givenDrugX or something similar. The function aims to (pseudo-)randomly assign to  an arm of a study, depending on block size - that is to say if block size is 8, 4 will be assigned to treatment and 4 to control (no treatment).

The code so far:

```
 public static bool nextAllocation<T>(int blockSize, IEnumerable<T> patientDataCollection, string allocationPropertyName)
 {
    int remainingAllocations = blockSize - patientDataCollection.Count();
    if (remainingAllocations <= 0) throw new Exception("All alocations within block accounted for");
    var p = typeof(T).GetProperty(allocationPropertyName);

    int remainingInterventions = blockSize/2 - patientDataCollection.Count(c => c.p);
    double Pintervention = (double)remainingInterventions / (double)remainingAllocations;
    double rdm = new Random().NextDouble();
    return (rdm <= Pintervention);
 }
```

this is of course flawed logic because the variable p does not relate to c.p referenced in the linq statement patientDataCollection.Count(c => c.p). obviously this statement is simply to count all elements which have a true value.

ASP is 4.0. Can anyone see how to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

You can pass to your method a `Func<T, bool>` which will be used for counting.

```
public static bool nextAllocation<T>(int blockSize, IEnumerable<T> patientDataCollection, Func<T,bool> predicate) 
{ 
    int remainingAllocations = blockSize - patientDataCollection.Count(); 
    if (remainingAllocations == 0) throw new Exception("All alocations within block accounted for"); 
    int remainingInterventions = blockSize/2 - patientDataCollection.Count(predicate); 
    double Pintervention = remainingInterventions / remainingAllocations; 
    double rdm = new Random().NextDouble(); 
    return (rdm <= Pintervention); 
}
```

An example of usage would be something like this:

```
var result = nextAllocation(10, collection, c=>c.interventionArm);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx) to get the value of the property:

```
int remainingInterventions = blockSize/2 - 
    patientDataCollection.Count(c => (bool)p.GetValue(c,null));
```

Add error checking as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Expressions

```
public static class ExpressionCreator
{
    public static Func<T, TProperty> CreatePropertyAccessExpression<T, TProperty>(string propertyName)
    {
        var tType = typeof (T);
        var property = tType.GetProperty(propertyName);
        var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(tType);
        var memberAccessExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameterExpression, property);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TProperty>>(memberAccessExpression, parameterExpression);
        return lambda.Compile();
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
    public class A
    {
        public bool Thing1 { get; set; }
        public bool Thing2 { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var @as = new A[10];
        for(var i = 0; i < @as.Length; i+=2)
        {
            @as[i] = new A {Thing1 = true};
            @as[i + 1] = new A {Thing2 = i%4 == 0};
        }

        var thing1Expression = ExpressionCreator.CreatePropertyAccessExpression<A, bool>("Thing1");
        var thing2Expression = ExpressionCreator.CreatePropertyAccessExpression<A, bool>("Thing2");
        Console.WriteLine(@as.Count(thing1Expression));
        Console.WriteLine(@as.Count(thing2Expression));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```